# List of NSDecimalNumbers in a dictionary saved to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to save a list of currency exchange rates inside a NSMutableDictionary. The keys to the dictionary are the currency codes (examples: @"AUD, @"CAD", etc) the values are NSDecimalNumbers with the conversion rate to US dollars. This all works fine when I first create the dictionary (after loading currency data from the web service). However, when I try to save the dictionary and reload it from NSUserDefaults, the values come back correctly (verified by NSLog of the dictionary) but they are __NSCFNumber instead of NSDecimalNumber.

This is how I save the dictionary:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:self.exchangeRatesDict forKey:kExchangeRateDictDefaultsKey];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

This is how I load it:

```
self.exchangeRatesDict = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kExchangeRateDictDefaultsKey] mutableCopy];
```

Is there a way to save the dictionary with a list of NSDecimalNumbers in NSUserDefaults, or do I need to save it in a different way?

Comment: Why are you calling `[userDefaults synchronize]`? You almost never need to actually call that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` inherits from `NSNumber`, which means it can be saved to a plist. That's all well and good. Of course, in the plist, it will almost certainly be represented as a floating-point number. And when reading the plist back in, these values will be deserialized as `NSNumber`s instead of `NSDecimalNumber`. This is because the plist format doesn't have explicit support for `NSDecimalNumber`, so it treats them just like any other `NSNumber`.

What you probably want to do is, instead of saving your dictionary directly, create a copy of the dictionary that replaces each `NSDecimalNumber` with its string representation. Then when you read it back in from `NSUserDefaults` you can do the inverse translation, converting each string back into an `NSDecimalNumber`.